# IIS 7.5: sending http status code 422 with custom errors on

Tags: error-handling, iis-7.5, http-status-codes, custom-errors

I use custom action filter in asp.net mvc app to return http status code 422 and json list of validation errors (basically serialized model state dictionary) to client, where I handle that with global ajaxError handler in jQuery.

All of this works on development enviroment, but my problem is when custom errors mode is on (`<system.webServer>/<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">`), IIS replaces response (json) with text "The custom error module does not recognize this error."

I'm having hard time properly configuring IIS to pass-through original response if status code is 422. Anyone did something similar?

Comment: Had the same issue when returning HTTP 402 Payment Required.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If web server is configured to pass through existing response, it will return json contents to browser.

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" existingResponse="PassThrough">
  </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

[MSDN: httpErrors Element [IIS Settings Schema]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690497%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Make the following settings for IIS 7.5, this works fine for me, the most important thing here was the installation of the `existingResponse="Replace"`:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" existingResponse="Replace" detailedMoreInformationLink="http://YouLink" lockAttributes="allowAbsolutePathsWhenDelegated,defaultPath">
            <error statusCode="401" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="C:\path\to\401.htm" responseMode="File" />
            <error statusCode="403" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="C:\path\to\403.htm" responseMode="File" />
            <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="C:\path\to\404.htm" responseMode="File" />
            <error statusCode="405" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="C:\path\to\405.htm" responseMode="File" />
            <error statusCode="406" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="C:\path\to\406.htm" responseMode="File" />
            <error statusCode="412" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="C:\path\to\412.htm" responseMode="File" />
            <error statusCode="500" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="C:\path\to\500.htm" responseMode="File" />
            <error statusCode="501" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="C:\path\to\501.htm" responseMode="File" />
            <error statusCode="502" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="C:\path\to\502.htm" responseMode="File" />
            <error statusCode="400" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="C:\path\to\400.htm" responseMode="File" />
</httpErrors>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if error pages are configured for your application in IIS. You need to add your custom error page for the status code eg: 429

[image: IIS Error pages configuration]

Add the status code HTMLstrong text page. It should resolve the issue

[image: Error HTML page configuration]