# ExpressJS: The custom error module does not recognize this error

Tags: node.js, azure, express, iisnode

I'm running an Express.JS backend, and have it set to return a 422 error with a custom message if a user attempts to sign up with an email that's already in use, like so:

```
const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email: email });
    if (existingUser) {
        return res.status(422).send({ error: 'Email is already in use' });
    }
```

However, the response I see on the front end is this:

`"response":{"data":"The custom error module does not recognize this error.","status":422,"statusText":"Unprocessable Entity"`

Something is, apparently, changing the error on the way to the front end.

I'm running this locally right now for development, but the production is deployed to Azure, so I have a Web.config file and an iisnode.yml one. I've added this code to the former, to make sure it's not causing the problem:

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough">
  </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

How do I go about troubleshooting this thing?

Comment: Is the issue related to expressjs, and how? The message you receive seems to come from some IIS. Have youy read this, already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12908764/iis-7-5-sending-http-status-code-422-with-custom-errors-on

Comment: Yes, read it and added the suggested code to Web.config. The issue persists.

Comment: Sorry for bothering, but I ask you again: how the issue is related to express?

Comment: I am using Express for my backend and returning errors from there.

I do not know why the errors are being transformed on their way to the front end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, but following should work.

```
return res.status(422).send('Email is already in use');
```

Comment: Nope, same thing.

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me after setting `<httpErrors>` like below:

[image]

The browser output:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I started off with this line, it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Try to restart your app service and clear the browser cache.