# Suppress "Custom error module does not recognize this" error message in IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

From a MVC controller action, I am setting `Response.StatusCode = 429;` and returning JsonResult. It's a requirement to send this status code for the action.
It works fine locally but on remote server, it's giving "The custom error module does not recognize this error.". 
How do I suppress IIS from showing this and just show the returned json as it is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IIS 7.5: sending http status code 422 with custom errors on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12908764/iis-7-5-sending-http-status-code-422-with-custom-errors-on)